# Extending a CustomOverlay class in BingMaps Api using Typescript

Tags: typescript, bing-maps

I'm converting a typescript application that uses **bing maps api 7** to **8**.
 As part of the migration I would like to convert the actual Overlay Component to a typescript class that implements the class **Microsoft.Maps.CustomOverlay**.
  As explained in this post in the msdn forums [error trying to create an overlay](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f53fdaae-f94e-4614-a7ec-3e3d3f4c4c4d/error-trying-to-create-an-overlay?forum=bingmaps), I'm facing a load error that I cannot solve, and I don't understand if the problem is the typescript compiled files is loaded before the bing maps api library is loaded and how to remove this error.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1):

I've created a number of modules that extend the CustomOverlay class in TypeScript without any issues. Here is one I created.

Here is the module code:

```
/// <reference path="MicrosoftMaps/Microsoft.Maps.d.ts"/>

/**
* The options that specify how to render a ground overlay on the map.
*/
interface IGroundOverlayOptions extends Microsoft.Maps.ICustomOverlayOptions {
    /** A background color that fills the bounding box area beneath the ground overlay. */
    backgroundColor?: string | Microsoft.Maps.Color;

    /** The bounding box to anchor the ground overlay to. */
    bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect;

    /** The URL to the image to anchor to the map as a ground overlay. */
    imageUrl: string;

    /** The opacity of the ground overlay image. */
    opacity?: number;

    /** An angle in degrees to rotate the overlay in a counter-clockwise direction where 0 = north, 90 = west, 180 = south, 270 = east */
    rotation?: number;

    /** A boolean value indicating if the ground overlay is visible or not. */
    visible?: boolean;
}

/**
 * A map overlay that binds an image to a bounding box area on the map.
 */
class GroundOverlay extends Microsoft.Maps.CustomOverlay {

    /***********************************
    * Private Properties
    ***********************************/

    /** The options used to define how the ground overlay is rendered. */
    private _options: IGroundOverlayOptions = {
        beneathLabels: true,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        bounds: null,
        imageUrl: null,
        opacity: 1,
        rotation: 0,
        visible: true
    };

    /** The image DOM element that is used to render the ground overlay. */
    private _img: HTMLImageElement;

    private _mapViewChangeEvent: Microsoft.Maps.IHandlerId;

    /***********************************
    * Constructor
    ***********************************/

    /**
     * @constructor
     * @param options The options used to render the ground overlay.
     */
    constructor(options: IGroundOverlayOptions) {
        super({
            beneathLabels: (typeof options.beneathLabels === 'boolean') ? options.beneathLabels : true
        });

        this.setOptions(options);
    }

    /***********************************
    * Public Properties
    ***********************************/

    /** Optional property to store any additional metadata for this layer. */
    public metadata: any;

    /***********************************
    * Public functions
    ***********************************/

    /**
     * Clears the ground overlay.
     */
    public clear() {
        //Reset the options back to the defaults.
        this._options = {
            backgroundColor: 'transparent',
            bounds: null,
            imageUrl: null,
            opacity: 1,
            rotation: 0,
            visible: true
        };

        this.setHtmlElement(null);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the background color of the ground overlay.
     * @returns The background color of the ground overlay.
     */
    public getBackgroundColor(): string | Microsoft.Maps.Color {
        return this._options.backgroundColor;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the bounding box that the ground overlay is bounded to.
     * @returns The bounding box that the ground overlay is bounded to.
     */
    public getBounds(): Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect {
        return this._options.bounds;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the url to the gorund overlay image.
     * @returns The url to the gorund overlay image.
     */
    public getImageUrl(): string {
        return this._options.imageUrl;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the opacity of the ground overlay.
     * @returns The opacity of the ground overlay.
     */
    public getOpacity(): number {
        return this._options.opacity;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the rotation of the ground overlay.
     * @returns The rotation of the ground overlay.
     */
    public getRotation(): number {
        return this._options.opacity;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a boolean indicating if the ground overlay is visible or not.
     * @returns A boolean indicating if the ground overlay is visible or not.
     */
    public getVisible(): boolean {
        return this._options.visible;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the options used to render the ground overlay.
     * @param options The options used to render the ground overlay.
     */
    public setOptions(options: IGroundOverlayOptions): void {
        if (options && typeof options.beneathLabels === 'boolean') {
            this._options.beneathLabels = options.beneathLabels;
        }

        if (typeof options.backgroundColor !== 'undefined') {
            this._options.backgroundColor = options.backgroundColor;
        }

        if (typeof options.opacity === 'number') {
            this._options.opacity = options.opacity;
            if (this._img) {
                this._img.style.opacity = this._options.opacity.toString();
            }
        }

        if (typeof options.rotation === 'number') {
            this._options.rotation = options.rotation;
            this._rotateGroundOverlay();
        }

        var reposition = false;

        if (typeof options.visible === 'boolean') {
            this._options.visible = options.visible;
            if (this._img) {
                if (options.visible) {
                    this._img.style.display = '';
                    reposition = true;
                } else {
                    this._img.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        }

        if (options.bounds instanceof Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect) {
            this._options.bounds = options.bounds;
            reposition = true;
        }

        if (typeof options.imageUrl !== 'undefined') {
            this._options.imageUrl = options.imageUrl;
            this._loadGroundOverlayImage();
        }

        if (reposition) {
            this._repositionGroundOverlay();
        }
    }

    /***********************************
    * Inherited Events
    ***********************************/

    /**
     * The event logic that processes when the ground overlay is added to the map.
     */
    public onAdd(): void {
        this._loadGroundOverlayImage();
    }

    /**
     * The event logic that processes when the ground overlay is initially loaded.
     */
    public onLoad(): void {
        this._repositionGroundOverlay();

        this._mapViewChangeEvent = Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(this.getMap(), 'viewchange', () => { this._repositionGroundOverlay() });
    }

    /**
     * The event logic that processes when the ground overlay is removed from the map.
     */
    public onRemove(): void {
        if (this._mapViewChangeEvent) {
            Microsoft.Maps.Events.removeHandler(this._mapViewChangeEvent);
        }
        this.setHtmlElement(null);
    }

    /***********************************
    * Private Functions
    ***********************************/

    /**
     * Loads the ground overlay image.
     */
    private _loadGroundOverlayImage(): void {
        if (this._options.imageUrl) {
            //Create an image element that will be used as the overlay.
            this._img = document.createElement('img');
            this._img.src = this._options.imageUrl;
            this._img.style.width = '100%';
            this._img.style.height = '100%';
            this._img.style.position = 'absolute';
            this._img.style.display = (this._options.visible) ? '' : 'none';

            if (this._options.backgroundColor) {
                if (this._options.backgroundColor instanceof Microsoft.Maps.Color) {
                    this._img.style.backgroundColor = (<Microsoft.Maps.Color>this._options.backgroundColor).toRgba();
                } else {
                    this._img.style.backgroundColor = <string>this._options.backgroundColor;
                }
            }

            if (typeof this._options.opacity === 'number') {
                this._img.style.opacity = this._options.opacity.toString();
            }

            this._rotateGroundOverlay();

            this.setHtmlElement(this._img);
        } else {
            this.setHtmlElement(null);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Rotates the ground overlay image.
     */
    private _rotateGroundOverlay(): void {
        if (this._img) {
            var rotation = this._options.rotation;
            if (!rotation) {
                rotation = 0;
            }

            rotation = rotation;

            var rotateTransform = 'rotate(' + rotation + 'deg)';
            this._img.style['-webkit-transform'] = rotateTransform;
            this._img.style['-moz-transform'] = rotateTransform;
            this._img.style['-ms-transform'] = rotateTransform;
            this._img.style['-o-transform'] = rotateTransform;
            this._img.style['transform'] = rotateTransform;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Repositions the ground overlay when the map moves.
     */
    private _repositionGroundOverlay(): void {
        var map = this.getMap();

        if (map && this._img && this._options.bounds && this._options.visible) {
            //Streach and position the image based on the bounding box pixel coordinates.
            var topLeft = <Microsoft.Maps.Point>map.tryLocationToPixel(this._options.bounds.getNorthwest(), Microsoft.Maps.PixelReference.control);
            var bottomRight = <Microsoft.Maps.Point>map.tryLocationToPixel(this._options.bounds.getSoutheast(), Microsoft.Maps.PixelReference.control);

            this._img.style.left = topLeft.x + 'px';
            this._img.style.top = topLeft.y + 'px';
            this._img.style.width = (bottomRight.x - topLeft.x) + 'px';
            this._img.style.width = (bottomRight.x - topLeft.x) + 'px';
            this._img.style.height = (bottomRight.y - topLeft.y) + 'px';
        }
    }
}

Microsoft.Maps.moduleLoaded('GroundOverlaysModule');
```

Here is the web app that implements this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #myMap {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap"></div>
    <script>
    var map;
    var groundOverlay;

    function initMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key',
            zoom: 13,
            center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(40.740, -74.18)
        });

        Microsoft.Maps.registerModule('GroundOverlaysModule', '../scripts/GroundOverlayModule.js');
        Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('GroundOverlaysModule', function () {
            groundOverlay = new GroundOverlay({
                bounds: Microsoft.Maps.LocationRect.fromEdges(40.773941, -74.22655, 40.712216, -74.12544),
                imageUrl: 'https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg'
            });
            map.layers.insert(groundOverlay);
        });
    }
    </script>

    <script async defer src="https://bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you use RegisterModule and LoadModule? This is a problem. Since the application has more than 100 ts files I compile all the ts in one single file, so Ts can handle semantic dependencies automatically.
To use this module loading mechanism I have to check if and how I can use multiple tsconfig.json files, so I can continue to compile the rest of the application In a single file and the components in a separate directory where the files are compiled one js file for every ts file.
Not a nice way

Comment: This example follows the modular framework that exists in Bing Maps. You can modify the code easily to fit your scenario and not use the Bing Maps module loading functionality. Simply remove the last line of the TS file.